# Error in building the Hyperledger Fabric v1.4.4 source code

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am attempting to build the Hyperledger Fabric source code. I am following the guide as given [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/dev-setup/build.html#building-hyperledger-fabric). I was able to successfully built the code using the `make dist-clean all` command. However, I wanted to test it on a fresh Virtual Machine. So, I followed the steps again but facing this issue while building the `gotools`.

```
Building dockerized gotools
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
Building github.com/maxbrunsfeld/counterfeiter -> counterfeiter
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
Building github.com/golang/dep v0.5.1 -> dep
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
Building golang.org/x/lint/golint -> golint
GOBIN=/opt/gotools/bin go install ./vendor/golang.org/x/lint/golint
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
Building golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports -> goimports
GOBIN=/opt/gotools/bin go install ./vendor/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
Building github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go -> protoc-gen-go
GOBIN=/opt/gotools/bin go install ./vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
Building github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo -> ginkgo
GOBIN=/opt/gotools/bin go install ./vendor/github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
Building github.com/axw/gocov/gocov -> gocov
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
Building github.com/AlekSi/gocov-xml -> gocov-xml
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
Building github.com/client9/misspell/cmd/misspell -> misspell
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
Building github.com/vektra/mockery/cmd/mockery -> mockery
package github.com/vektra/mockery/cmd/mockery: cannot find package "github.com/vektra/mockery/cmd/mockery" in any of:
        /opt/go/src/github.com/vektra/mockery/cmd/mockery (from $GOROOT)
        /opt/gotools/obj/src/github.com/vektra/mockery/cmd/mockery (from $GOPATH)
make[1]: *** [gotool.mockery] Error 1
gotools.mk:59: recipe for target 'gotool.mockery' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'
gotools.mk:64: recipe for target '/opt/gotools/bin/mockery' failed
make: *** [/opt/gotools/bin/mockery] Error 2
Makefile:253: recipe for target '.build/docker/gotools' failed
make: *** [.build/docker/gotools] Error 2
```

However, when I run the find command as follows: `sudo find / -name "*mockery*"`, I get the following output:

```
/home/<user>/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/.build/docker/gotools/obj/src/github.com/vektra/mockery
/home/<user>/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/.build/docker/gotools/obj/src/github.com/vektra/mockery/.mockery.yaml
/home/<user>/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/.build/docker/gotools/obj/src/github.com/vektra/mockery/pkg/mockery_test.go
/home/<user>/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/.build/docker/gotools/obj/src/github.com/vektra/mockery/pkg/mockery.go
/home/<user>/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/.build/docker/gotools/obj/src/github.com/vektra/mockery/cmd/mockery_test.go
/home/<user>/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/.build/docker/gotools/obj/src/github.com/vektra/mockery/cmd/mockery.go
```

Then I run, the `make dist-clean all` command again without making any changes, and it directly skips to throw this new error:

```
Installing chaintool
curl -fL https://nexus.hyperledger.org/content/repositories/releases/org/hyperledger/fabric/hyperledger-fabric/chaintool-1.1.3/hyperledger-fabric-chaintool-1.1.3.jar > .build/bin/chaintool
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nexus.hyperledger.org
Makefile:224: recipe for target '.build/bin/chaintool' failed
make: *** [.build/bin/chaintool] Error 6
```

I am making use of Hyperledger Fabric v1.4.4 tree. I did not make any changes to any files locally before the build. It would be helpful if someone can guide me in solving this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve these issues by switching to `v1.4` latest release. The 2 changes in the latest `v1.4` release that solve these issues are:

1. The `github.com/vektra/mockery` can be correctly built with change shown [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/gotools.mk#L19).
2. The URL for pulling chaintool files is changed as shown [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/Makefile#L84).